# The eyes have it

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading a book, "Word Power Made Easy". One section of it was titled as:

> The eyes have it.

The section dealt with specialists for eyes and their respective fields. On googling the sentence, I could only find some references to some songs.

So, I want to ask what does it mean in this context?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The title is a [pun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun). It is meant to sound like "[The *ayes* have it](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20ayes%20have%20it)."

[**Aye**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_and_no#Colloquial_forms) (pronounced just like *eye*) is a synonym for "yes," and is still used in parts of the U.K. and Ireland.

In [parliamentary procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_procedure), **the ayes** refers to the members of a congress, parliament or other formal meeting who voted "yes" on something. It is used, for example, in the U.S. Congress, the U.K. Parliament, corporate board meetings, and so on.

In this context, "to have it" means "to prevail." Therefore, **the ayes have it** means that there were enough "yes" votes for the measure to pass or succeed.

As Michael Harvey suggests in his comment:

> It's [just] a stupid topic-related pun, like "Eye am here to help you" said the ophthalmologist.

Comment: @typelA- what I essentially want to ask is how it's related to the content which it covers.

Comment: @kelvin Next time please include everything you know in your question so that potential answerers don't waste time explaining things you already know.

Comment: @kelvin I don't know how the title relates to the content because I haven't read the book, but it's possible it has no deeper meaning at all: some writers just like to make puns!